# Using ddply to aggregate over irregular time periods in longitudinal data

Tags: r

I'm looking for help adapting two existing scripts.

I am working with a longitudinal dataset, and aggregating a key variable over time periods.  I have a variable for both `weeks` and `months`. I'm able to aggregate over both `weeks` and `months` - but my goal is to aggregate over weeks for the *first six weeks*, and then move over to aggregating by months *after 6 weeks+*.

Aggregating by weeks and months is easy enough...

> df.summary_week <- ddply(df,  .(weeks), summarise,
>                       var.mean = mean(var,na.rm=T))

Which yields something like:

```
weeks    var.mean
1        3.99
2        5.44
3        6.7
4        8.100
5        2.765
6        2.765
7        3.765
8        4.765
9        1.765
10       4.765
11       1.765
```

And then aggregating by month would yield something similar:

> df.summary_months <- ddply(df,  .(months), summarise,
>                       var.mean = mean(var,na.rm=T))

```
months    var.mean
1        5.00
2        3.001
3        4.7
4        7.100
```

My initial idea was to simply subset the two datasets with cut points and then bind them together, but I don't know how to do that when the 1-month aggregation starts at 6 weeks rather than 8.

Thoughts, R wizards?

Comment: Could you just ddply by months using `df[df$weeks>6,]` and then rbind that to the results of ddply-ing by weeks using `df[df$weeks<=6]`?

Comment: @thelatemail I might be wrong, but wouldn't the first month thus just be a biweekly aggregate of the 3rd and 4th of weeks the month? The reason why I'm aggregating is due to the n in each bucket, so a biweekly average isn't going to work :(

Comment: Yep. Since a month is a bit of an undefined quality, would you be happy to aggregate every 4 weeks as a "month" from week 7 onwards?

Comment: @thelatemail, so the "weeks" and "months" are actually calculated based on the difference in the number of days between a set start point and the date of the observations, and then rounded (by .5). I think that aggregating by 4 weeks after week 7 is fine, given that as you point out it's an inexact science...Ideally, I'd be able to set different cut points though.

Answer (score 0):

Basic example data.

```
dat <- data.frame(var=1:24,weeks=1:24,months=rep(1:6,each=4))
```

Means for first 6 grps should be just 1:6, then means will be values 
for subsequent 4 week periods. E.g. (mean(7:10) = 8.5 etc).

Make a suitable group identifier going from weeks to months:

```
dat$grp <- findInterval(dat$weeks,seq(7,max(dat$weeks),4)) + 6
dat$grp <- ifelse(dat$grp==6,dat$weeks,dat$grp)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 11 11
```

Group the data:

```
ddply(dat, .(grp), summarise, var.mean = mean(var,na.rm=T))

   grp var.mean
1    1      1.0
2    2      2.0
3    3      3.0
4    4      4.0
5    5      5.0
6    6      6.0
7    7      8.5
8    8     12.5
9    9     16.5
10  10     20.5
11  11     23.5
```

Comment: I 100% understand your approach...but am getting an error that says 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite. I checked to make sure weeks is numeric, and it is...thoughts? –

Comment: @roody - my guess would be that `max(dat$weeks)` is returning NA or Inf somehow. You can see the example works with basic data so there must be something funky in the input data you are using.

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating a new grouping column?

```
set.seed(1618)
dat <- data.frame(week = sample(1:26, 200, replace = TRUE), 
                  value = rpois(200, 2))

dat <- within(dat, {
  idx <- cut(week, c(0, 6, seq(10, max(week), by = 4)))
})
# head(dat)
#   week value     idx
# 1    6     1   (0,6]
# 2   16     2 (14,18]
# 3    9     1  (6,10]
# 4   13     2 (10,14]
# 5    8     2  (6,10]
# 6   16     2 (14,18]

library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(idx), summarise, 
      mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))
#       idx     mean
# 1   (0,6] 1.870968
# 2  (6,10] 2.259259
# 3 (10,14] 2.171429
# 4 (14,18] 1.931034
# 5 (18,22] 1.560000
# 6 (22,26] 1.954545

# checking a couple values
mean(dat[dat$week %in% 1:6, 'value'])
# [1] 1.870968
mean(dat[dat$week %in% 7:10, 'value'])
# [1] 2.259259
mean(dat[dat$week %in% 23:26, 'value'])
# [1] 1.954545
```